# Remove weird Japanese Characters from Google Geocode results

Tags: javascript, regex, google-maps-api-3, replace

I'm using Google Maps API v3 and Reverse Geocode to get City Name, Neighborhood, Locality and Country using Latitude and Longitude.

Everything works fine but some results appear with weird characters, ex:

```
        {
           "long_name" : "ポンペーイア",
           "short_name" : "ポンペーイア",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
```

The correct info should be "Pompeia" and not these characters. I know this is some kind of Google Bug because the same characters are displayed on Google Maps Url but I want to at least remove these characters, so I've tried to replace this Characters using JS and Regex but with no success.

```
var neighborhood = results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
var clean = neighborhood.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

or

```
var clean = neighborhood.replace("ポンペーイア", "Clean Text");
```

These codes can change any other "utf-8" characters but it seems that the Japanese characters are not recognized.

Any ideas ?

Comment: @hwnd Nothing happens, the result remains ポ ン ペ ー イ ア

Comment: Why are these characters weird? As it seems it's the [**japanese word for Pompeia**](https://translate.google.de/#ja/en/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2)

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I already knew that, It's weird because my language has no Japanese character, at all.

Comment: @hwnd, It worked perfectly, Thanks! Could you explain the code? I'd like to know if this code will remove any japanese character from my Vars or if it works for that specific word only (ポンペーイア).

Comment: @suicidebilly Added explanation.

Comment: Thought I was the only one having this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is long and ugly but should do the trick.

```
var clean = neighborhood.replace(/[\W\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4‌​e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf]/g, '');
```

The following ranges:

- `\u3000-\u303f` matches Japanese punctuation characters.
- `\u3040-\u309f` matches Hiragana.
- `\u30a0-\u30ff` matches Katakana.
- `\uff00-\uff9f` matches Full-width Roman and Half-width Katakana.
- `\u4e00-\u9faf` matches CJK (Common and uncommon Kanji)
- `\u3400-\u4dbf` matches CJK ext. A

Reference:

- [Unicode Kanji Table](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml)